# Distinguish between number and object quickly

Tags: javascript, performance

I've got a complex data structure in JavaScript composed out of numbers and containers (arrays in this case). What would be the fastest and/or most memory efficient way to store and process this? Is there something non-obvious, better speed and/or memory-wise, than for example [ [ 1, 2], [3, 4] ] which requires something similar to typeof to distinguish between tree branches and leaves when scanning it? The structure is very large with about a million numbers.

I've set up a jsperf test to evaluate some methods of distinguishing between numbers and objects, and typeof seems fastest except in Opera and IE:

http://jsperf.com/typeof-number-vs-object

Comment: Seems like an Opera bug to me :)

Comment: @Jack: `{}.length` is also `undefined`, so that's only suitable to check against arrays / strings ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus I assumed it could only be arrays or numbers. In any case it's not very fast anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
isNaN(myVar)
```

returns `true` id `myVar` is *not*  a number, false otherwise.

**[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)**

Although, apparently, this function isn't entirely bug-free... (See the docs I linked to)

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Added to the jsperf. isNaN is very slow, but that's very good to know.

Comment: @jjrv: I saw you added it. I'm quite surprised it's that slow o.O

Comment: much like +myVar, isNaN(myVar) converts first to string, then number. Serializing an array can take some time.